# pushViewController pushes nil

Tags: objective-c, viewcontroller

I am trying to push a *view controller* to the screen. The push is successful but when I later try to access any property of the pushed view controller including textboxes and labels, they are all *nil*.

How do I avoid this?

I am doing it this way because I need my code to decide which view controller to push. Any help is much appreciated.

```
 myVC *vC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vC animated:YES];
```

Comment: Are you debugging your build in "release" environment? Make sure you don't.

Comment: Your push is probably fine, how are you trying to access the properties though?

Answer (score 0):

After the code you've wrote, you will need to either approach your properties like this:

```
vC.property = assignedValue;
```

Make sure you have synthesized your properties, or initialised them with a setter in the vC's viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboard , You can actually use prepareForSegue for transferring data between ViewControllers.

And be sure your properties are declared in .h file. You can't access .m file properties.

Hope this helps.